# WPF concurrency model

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, unmanaged

I am working on a C# WPF application which calls an unmanaged C++ DLL functions using PInvoke. The WPF app was created using Blend.

The unmanaged C++ DLL calls `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` from a PInvoke function. I get an error message at this line of code saying `"COM library already initialized with incompatible concurrency model"`

I am assuming WPF is inherently STAThread. Am I right?

How can I fix the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the WPF UI thread will initialize the COM apartment state as single threaded.  If it isn't single a single threaded apartment a whole bunch of stuff will fail.

You'll need to start a new thread and call the your C++ DLL and ensure that the apartment state of that thread is multi-threaded.  A thread's apartment state can be set using [Thread.SetApartmentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx), but all new threads are multi-threaded by default.